# Creating a new repo from a directory of old repo

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I am very new to bazaar and I am exploring the features of it (and of version control system)

I have a bazaar repo, lets call it 'foo'. Under foo repo I have a directory, lets call it 'projects'.

so, I want to create a separate bazaar repo with only projects directory & I want to retain the log too. I mean to say, everything that is related to project folder present in log file, should be available with this new repo.

I tried export command, but I just got the directory without any log.

Any pointers where I should look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `fastimport` plugin:

```
bzr fast-export /path/to/orig/project | \
    bzr fast-import-filter -i project1/ | \
        bzr fast-import - /path/to/new/project1
```

(I broke the line for readability)

- The first command dumps the revisions of the branch at the specified path to standard output
- The second command filters the revisions, selecting only the ones that affect the `project1/` directory. The trailing `/` is important.
- The third command imports the revisions from the standard input to the specified branch. If the branch does not exist, `bzr` will create a shared repository with a branch named `trunk` in it.

For more details, see the help pages:

- `bzr help fast-export`
- `bzr help fast-import-filter`
- `bzr help fast-import`

The `fastimport` plugin is included in the default installation on Windows and Mac OS X. If you have a more exotic setup, I recommend installing it with `pip`. I don't remember 100% the package name, maybe `bzr-fastimport`. You will also need the `fastimport` python library.

Comment: Thank you very much, shall try this soon.